# On the definition of well defined object

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

In the book **Discrete mathematical structures** by Kolman-Busby-Ross, a **set** is defined as a collection of well-defined objects & a **well-defined object** is defined as an object for which it is possible to decide if it belongs to a collection or not.

So whether or not an object belongs to a collection is dependent on no perspective, a universal perspective or from the perspective of an individual WRT which it is decided whether a object belongs to a collection or not?

Let's say that we've a collection, A: "Top 10 best actors in the world" & there are N different people (e.g. P1,...,PN) who have decided the members of the collections differently as:
A1 = {a11, ..., a110} for P1,
...
AN = {aN1, ..., aN10} for PN

Let's assume that values in A1,...,AN stays constant. Then is the collection A a set?

Or is there another way to define well-defined set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very bad definition for many reasons.

First, it relies on the informal notion of "deciding whether an object is in a collection". This immediately destroys the entire project.

Consider a computer program $P$ in some fixed programming language (perhaps a Turing machine if you want to be formal) that takes, as input, a single natural number.

We can consider the collection of input numbers for which $P$ eventually terminates (eventually stops running and finishes computation).

There is no effective procedure, in general, for deciding whether $P$ halts when given the input $0$.

So we cannot decide, for an arbitrary collection, whether $0$ is in that collection. Therefore, $0$ is not a well-defined object.

Hopefully, it's clear that we want $0$ to be well-defined. Otherwise, it's going to be difficult to get any math done.

Second, it does not restrict "sets" enough. We clearly want sets themselves to be well-defined objects. So intuitively, this allows us to form the set of all sets. But that immediately runs headlong into many famous paradoxes, most notably Russell's paradox (consider the set of all sets that do not contain themselves).

This begs the question of how to define sets. The primary answer is: don't.

There is no answer to "what is a set". There is only a list of properties about sets that we can use to prove things about them.

Traditionally, the most commonly used list of the properties of sets has been the axioms of ZFC. These axioms state common-sense properties of sets like "If two sets have the same elements, they are equal". These axioms also state methods of constructing new sets from existing ones. They allow you to define operations like union, intersection, and power set and state what the properties of these operations are.

There are also other approaches to set theory. Some early tries include Quine's New Foundations. More modern set theories are often based in category theory (such as ETCS, which is equivalent to a version of ZFC with fewer axioms), and these theories tend to be even more abstract about what sets "really are" then ZFC is.